# Gcc -g What happens？

Tags: debugging, gcc

The assembly file is obtained by using gcc -g -S, and the part of .s file is as follows：

```
.L3:
    .loc 1 22 11
    mov eax, DWORD PTR -12[rbp]
    mov edx, eax
    mov rcx, QWORD PTR .refptr._ZSt4cout[rip]
    call    _ZNSolsEi
    .loc 1 22 18
    mov rdx, QWORD PTR .refptr._ZSt4endlIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_[rip]
    mov rcx, rax
    call    _ZNSolsEPFRSoS_E
    .loc 1 23 7
    mov DWORD PTR -12[rbp], 0
    .loc 1 12 2
    add DWORD PTR -4[rbp], 1
    jmp .L6
```

What does .loc 1 22 11 stand for?

Answer (score 1):

When the `-g` flag is added to gcc it directs the compiler to add debugging information. `.loc` appears only when the compiler generates debugging information with `-g` flag:

https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.38/as/Loc.html#Loc